# Is there a way to create a new df feature with multiple factor levels in one line?

Tags: r

Is there a way to add a column, with multiple factor levels that depend on an existing column, to a data frame in one line?  Does the answer change if the new column has two factor levels vs more than two?

```
#two factor level example
df <- mtcars

df$mpg_rating <- "bad"
df$mpg_rating[df$mpg>30] <- "good"
```

```
#three factor level example
df <- mtcars

df$mpg_rating <- "bad"
df$mpg_rating[df$mpg>20] <- "ok"
df$mpg_rating[df$mpg>30] <- "good"
```

I'd like to create "mpg_rating" in 1 line instead of 2 or 3

Comment: The `cut` function may be useful here. Check `cut(x = mtcars$mpg, breaks = ((1:4) * 10), labels = c("bad", "ok", "good"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cut`

```
transform(df, mpg_rating=cut(mpg, breaks=c(-Inf, 20, 30, Inf), labels = c("bad", "ok", "good")))
```

Answer (score 1):

An one-liner would be with `findInterval`

```
df$mpg_rating <- with(df, c("bad", "ok", "good")[findInterval(mpg, c(20, 30))+1])
```

NOTE: It fits well in a single line